# Code works in Visuall Studio Coe when i use debug but not when i run in terminal python

Tags: python, visual-studio

When i run in terminal i get the [Errno 2] No such file or directory error, but when i use debug mode it works.

the error occurs here,

```
list = open(filename, "r")
```

the code also works with IDLE

Answer (score 3):

Your debugger is most likely running in a different location than your terminal.  cd your terminal to where the file is located, or try using the absolute path instead of a relative one.

Answer (score 0):

If you add these few lines in your code and run it using your IDE or Terminal, you'll notice the difference:

```
import os

curdir = os.getcwd()
print('My current directory is {}'.format(curdir))

fullpath_to_filename = os.path.join(curdir, filename)
print('When I run `open(filename)`, python sees: {}'.format(fullpath_to_filename))

print('This filepath is {}valid'.format('' if os.path.exists(fullpath_to_filename) else 'not '))
```

You'll likely experience something similar to below:

```
# on IDE:

My current directory is c:\Users\me\Projects\
When I run `open(filename)`, python sees: c:\Users\me\Projects\test.txt
This filepath is valid

# on Terminal:

My current directory is c:\Programs\Python38\
When I run `open(filename)`, python sees: c:\Programs\Python38\test.txt
This filepath is not valid
```

Solution: use absolute path for your `filename`, or `os.chdir(...)` to the correct parent path before location `filename`.  I would recommend the former to avoid managing directories.